# Popover Bootstrap, скрытие popover при щелчке вне элемента. Как?

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать, чтобы `popover` скрывался при щелчке в любом месте страницы, а не только по повторному щелчку по кнопке?
Опция `trigger` не подходит. Необходимо, чтобы при потере фокуса `popover` не сворачивался.

Вот: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nB4U6/)

```js
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
    margin: 100px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
<div class="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link</a> 
    <div class="head hide">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content hide">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something…">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
</div>
<div class="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link II</a> 
    <div class="head hide">Lorem Ipsum II</div>
    <div class="content hide">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something II…">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

что-то типо того: http://jsfiddle.net/nB4U6/129/
хорошо бы еще анимацию затухании добавить, ну это вы уж как сами захотите

```js
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
 if(event.target.nodeName == 'HTML'){
  $('.popover.fade').hide().remove();
 }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 100px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link</a> 
    <div class="head hide">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content hide">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something…">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
</div>
<div class="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link II</a> 
    <div class="head hide">Lorem Ipsum II</div>
    <div class="content hide">
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something II…">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
</div>
```

Был добавлен обработчик события щелчка на всём документе.